# How to find End Statement in large project

Tags: excel, vba

I've inherited a large Excel VBA project in which the End Statement has been used. Since the End statemement terminates abruptly, without processing Unload etc. events, and resets all variables, I'd like to replace them all. However, it's hard to find the few instances of End among the huge number of End If, End Sub, End Function, End With, etc.

So -- is there a good way to find instances of End without finding instances of End If, End Sub, etc.?

Thanks,

Greg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there isn't a way to find it directly using the VBA Editor that I know of , even pattern matching wont achieve it , but this works...

Replace All `"End "` to `"End2"`   (2 for example)

[image]

Then find `"End"`  (Find Whole Word Only)

[image]

Put a comment after it so you can find it in future

```
End 'End
```

Then Replace All `"End2"` to `"End "`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like Notepad++ which is a free text/code editor which supports regular expression searches.

Copy your code into Notepad++ and use the Find & Replace function, change the search type to regular expression and then search for "^End$"